# Two specific sets in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, matrices

Let $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries. Let $r$ be a positive integer with $r\le n$. Define
$$A_r=\{X \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) \mid \mbox{Rank}(X)\ge r\}$$ and
 $$B_r=\{X \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) \mid \mbox{Rank}(X)\le r\}$$
State whether $A_r$, $B_r$ are closed or open.

Okay for $r=n$ its easy. For general $r\neq n$, I was able to deduce certain properties like $B_r$ is not open, $A_r$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a matrix of rank $k$. In particular, $M$ has an invertible submatrix $N \in GL(k,\mathbb{R})$. Let $p : M(n,\mathbb{R} ) \to M(k,\mathbb{R})$ denote the projection such that $p(M)=N$. Let $f = \det \circ p$. Because $f$ is continuous and $f(M) \neq 0$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $M$ such that $f(X) \neq 0$ for all $X \in V$. Therefore, such a $X$ has an invertible $(k \times k)$-submatrix, hence $\mathrm{rank}(X) \geq k$.

Consequently, $A_r$ is open. In some sense, it is a consequence of the fact that matrix rank is lower semi-continuous.

For $B_r$, notice that $B_r= A_{r+1}^c$.